# Json Parser not working inside higher order functions in scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, playframework, play-json

I have a dstream and trying to parse each string into an object using play json library.
It works on the outside but it doesn't work on the inside. It says no implicits found.

```
val textStream: ReceiverInputDStream[String] = streamingContext.socketTextStream("localhost",12345)

textStream.map{record=>
  Json.parse(record).as[Car] //this doesn't works, it shows as: Json.parse(record).as[Car](...)

}
```

This is defined in the companion object of Car:

```
object Car {
implicit val carFormat = Json.format[Car]
}
```

It works  when implicits are given explicitly inside and it seems a bit odd.

```
 textStream.map{record=>
  implicit val carFormat = Json.format[Car] //How do I avoid this
  Json.parse(record).as[Car]
}
```

How do I avoid defining inside and make it work by defining the implicits outside ? 
I also tried importing explicit inside the companion object but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried to pass `carFormat` as a parameter to `as[Car]` call?

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk   `Json.parse(record).as[Car](carFormat)` works then why implicits isn't working ?

Comment: Usually that should just work. But since you've not shown a complete, minimal example we can only guess. My guess would be that you've defined the `Car` object in a different package than the `Car` class... Maybe you have ambiguous implicits? Show the concrete error message.